# Use method within class to define a global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Foo:
    def add(self, a, b):
        return (a+b)
    def sub(self, a, b):
        return (a-b)
    C = add(1,2)
```

> TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

How can I use a method within that class? When using a method within the class it is defined in, what should I pass in for the 'self' parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you're getting at.  The summary and description don't seem to match. I'll try to answer both to the best of my ability though.

```
GLOBAL_VAR = int()

class Foo:
    def add(self, a, b):
        return (a+b)

    @staticmethod
    def sub(a, b):
        return (a - b)

    def call_add(self, *args):
        global GLOBAL_VAR
        GLOBAL_VAR = self.add(*args)

C = Foo().add(1, 2)
D = Foo.sub(1, 2)
Foo().call_add(1, 2)

print(GLOBAL_VAR, C, D)
```

So the explanation.

- If you want to update a global variable in a class method you have to bring it into the method with the it with the `global` keyword
- if you want to access a class method you have to instantiate the class in the `C = Foo().method()` example
- if you just want to call the method directly you can remove self and make it a static method in the `D = Foo.sub()` example.
- if you want to call add in the class you need to call `self.add`

Hope that helps!